# loop.index is not returning correct number inside nested loop with inline if conditional

Tags: forloop, count

I'm getting incorrect loop.index results with the following code. It returns "1" for each entry returned. Is there a different way this needs to be written?

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for refund in order.transactions if refund.type == "refund" %}
        {{ loop.index  }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You want the loop index of the inner for loop or do you want the loop index of the outer?  If each order only has 1 transaction, I'd expect your code to output `1`, `orders` number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to display the loop index of the outer for loop.

To do that, Twig provides a [`loop.parent`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#accessing-the-parent-context-in-nested-loops) context.

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for refund in order.transactions if refund.type == "refund" %}
        {{ loop.parent.loop.index  }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you're looking to get the total number of times the inner loop gets hit, then something like this should work:

```
{% set loopCount = 0 %}

{% for order in orders %}
    {% for refund in order.transactions if refund.type == "refund" %}
        {% set loopCount = loopCount + 1 %}
        {{ loopCount  }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was looking for the inner loop count. I see your comment above and I think I understand what's happening now... What I'm looking to do is number a table column from 1...XXX. Let me try {{ loop.parent.loop.index  }}

Comment: Negative... Using {{ loop.parent.loop.index  }} didn't get me the count numbers either... I'll see if I can return a row number another way.

Comment: Hrm... check my edit and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That did the trick!